# C odd if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I know it is probably silly and easy question,but I am pretty new to programming.I have the following question about an if operator I saw in one program.Here is the code:

```
  d= -12.4;
  if(d) printf("%d \n", abs((int)d));
  else printf("%d \n",(int)(d));
```

Why does it print 12 instead of -12.
I mean why is this statement even true ?

```
if(d)
```

I thought a statement with only 1 variable is not even syntactically correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically

```
if(d)
```

is the same as

```
if(d != 0)
```

it is perfectly valid code.

Comment: @user3183584 additionally you are printing abs() value using %d that is the reason floating part not appears

Answer (score 6):

In C any expression that is not zero is considered true. And identifiers (like the variable name) is a valid expression, otherwise you would not be able to use variable names anywhere.